# Install specific version of opencv with github or other official repository

Tags: opencv

What i want to do is to install on my computer opencv with a very specific version (2.4.10).
I tried to switch the branch  on github but it does not give me what i need.

I only need opencv core package.

Do you know where i can download this version on officials repositories ? Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4.10

Answer (score 0):

Below is the method to clone `OpenCV 2.4.10` through `TortoiseGit 2.4.0.3`.

1. Clone `OpenCV HEAD` from `https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`.
2. In the cloned directory, right click and select `TortoiseGit` from the popup menu. From the sub menu, select `Switch/Checkout`.
3. In `Switch/Checkout` menu, select `OpenCV-2.4.10` from `Branch` or `2.4.10` from `Tag`.

[image: After the switch completes, you can u]

See `show log` to verify if the right version is cloned or not.

[image]

Hope this help.

**EDIT:**

The image below shows the subfolder with the `opencv-2.4.10 core` package from the GitHub clone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i do not see opencv-core library. I just need opencv-core. Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what the core library you refer? The `HEAD` url showed about is the basic `OpenCV` source, not the `opencv_contrub`.

Comment: Just check the cloned repository in my PC. There is a folder named `~\modules\core`, see **EDIT** on the Answer. That's the source of `opencv-core` you are looking for?

Comment: In this old version of opencv there were multiple librarries like opencv_core and opencv_imgproc

Comment: All the lib are under the `~\modules` folder. Have you found that?